# Create Tableau Online Schedules

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau online comes with some pre-packaged schedules that you can choose from but I can't find anywhere to define my own schedule times. Specifically, I need some reports to be delivered on weekends. To make a subscription the user relies on the schedules that are defined but all the pre loaded schedules are for weekdays and hourly. I am `Site role:Site Administrator` as defined in `My Account Settings` . Has anyone found a solution to this? Everything I have found relates to Server. In Online, the user does not see the `+New Schedule` button as in the Server instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bernardo's direction I was able to find this explanation. The `Create Schedules` function is a Server admin only role and this role is available in Tableau Server and not Tableau Online.

[Tableau's online help](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/users_site_roles.htm)

```
General capabilities allowed with each site role

Server Administrator: ****(Tableau Server only)****: The server 
administrator has full access to all server and site functionality, all 
content on the server, and all users.

Site Administrator: Site administrators can manage groups, projects, 
workbooks, and data sources (including connection information) for the 
site. On Tableau Server on-premises, the server administrator determines
whether site administrators can add users and assign site roles and site 
membership. On Tableau Online, site administrators are allowed these 
capabilities.
```

UPDATE:

I received an email to begin testing custom subscriptions in the latest Online Beta release.

> Here at Tableau, we listen to user feedback to improve our products. One of the most popular feature requests has been about schedules in Tableau Online. Folks would like to allow all users to customize schedules for extracts or view updates, rather than being limited to pre-defined schedules.
>
> Today we are pleased to announce that our new Custom Schedules for subscriptions feature is available to you for preview. We’d like to get your feedback on the feature before it goes public.

Answer (score 2):

Creating new schedules is a Server Admin role only capability. Site admins cannot create them.

Comment: Thanks Bernardo! Is there a server admin role for Online?

Comment: I would imagine so. Check with your sales rep for information. We don't use Online at my company.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabcmd commands to login to your site on tableau online and manually refresh/download your workbooks and then use the help of powershell to send subscription emails to the audience.